# Commanders with at least four colors in their color identity

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am looking for a list of all legendary creatures with the number of colors in their color identity equal to or greater than four.

In Gatherer I can only get a list using the mana colors in the cost of the cards. For example: [WUBRG spells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?output=compact&color=%20%5BW%5D%20%5BU%5D%20%5BB%5D%20%5BR%5D%20%5BG%5D).

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a alternate search engine, there is http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/

There is an option under colour to use colour identity but this is more geared towards "If I have xyz coloured commander, what cards can I use". With a bit of creative searching, I have made the following queries:

[WUBRG](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]c&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]rgwu&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]gwub&display=standard&sort=name+)
(Gives you all the legendary creatures you can't put in all four colour or colourless commander decks)

[WUBR](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=+color[contains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]rgwu&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]gwub&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]c&display=standard&sort=name+)
[UBRG](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[contains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]rgwu&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]gwub&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]c&display=standard&sort=name+)
[BRGW](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[contains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]rgwu&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]gwub&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]c&display=standard&sort=name+)
[RWUB](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[contains-id]rgwu&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]gwub&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]c&display=standard&sort=name+)
[GWUB](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=%20type[contains]Creature&1[]=%20type[contains]Legendary&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]wurb&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]ubrg&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]brgw&1[]=%20color[notcontains-id]rgwu&1[]=%20color[contains-id]gwub&1[]=+color[notcontains-id]c&display=standard&sort=name+)
(Gives you all the legendary creatures you can use in the particular four colour combo but not can't use in the other four colour combinations plus colourless commander decks)

There is also the legendary creatures with partner but you can quickly find them by searching for partner in the card text ([Commanders with partner](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/cardsearch/?1[]=and&1[]=+text[contains]partner&display=standard&sort=name+))

As with gatherer, when you conduct a search with only one result, it will redirect to that card page.

Answer (score 4):

The four-color commanders in Commander 2016 were a big deal because there *weren't* any before. (People sometimes use the Nephilim, but they're not actually legendary.) So, there are [the five-color ones you already know how to find](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20[W]%20[U]%20[B]%20[R]%20[G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22]), and the five from Commander 2016.

It's not too hard to go through all the possibilities to confirm this, but since there's only one result for each query, these searches all currently redirect right to the card:

- [WUBR](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20[W]%20[U]%20[B]%20[R]%20![G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22])
- [WUBG](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20[W]%20[U]%20[B]%20![R]%20[G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22])
- [WURG](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20[W]%20[U]%20![B]%20[R]%20[G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22])
- [WBRG](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20[W]%20![U]%20[B]%20[R]%20[G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22])
- [UBRG](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20![W]%20[U]%20[B]%20[R]%20[G]&type=%20[creature]%20[%22Legendary%22])

If someday they print some more, those queries will find them! But don't hold your breath; there's not a lot of design space in four-color cards. Since they're good for commander but not for standard, if they ever do make more, there's a good chance it'd be in a commander set (but not too soon after the current one).

Comment: What those queries wont find are cards like [General Tazri](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407529) if they ever do four colour versions. For some reason, devoid cards are also considered colourless for searches if they ever decided to bring that back. I don't think there is a general gatherer query that will catch all edge cases though. They really need to update gatherer search engine but since comments have been broken for years now, I don't see that changing any time soon.

Comment: That is right. The filters don't consider the concept of color identity used in the commander format.

Answer (score 4):

The site [EDHRec](https://edhrec.com) has pages for each color identity with all the legal commanders (including possible partner pairs). For example the [URBG](https://edhrec.com/commanders/ubrg/) pages shows:

- [Yidris, Maelstrom Wielder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYidris%2c%20Maelstrom%20Wielder%5d)
- [Kydele, Chosen of Kruphix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKydele%2c%20Chosen%20of%20Kruphix%5d) + [Vial Smasher the Fierce](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVial%20Smasher%20the%20Fierce%5d)
- [Thrasios, Triton Hero](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThrasios%2c%20Triton%20Hero%5d) + Vial Smasher the Fierce
- [Glint-Eye Nephilim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlint-Eye%20Nephilim%5d) (Unofficial)
- [Ikra Shidiqi, the Usuper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIkra%20Shidiqi%2c%20the%20Usuper%5d) + [Kraum, Ludevic's Opus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKraum%2c%5d%2b%5bLudevic%27s%5d%2b%5bOpus%5d)
- [Silas Renn, Seeker Adept](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSilas%20Renn%2c%20Seeker%20Adept%5d) + [Tana, the Sloodsower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTana%2c%20the%20Sloodsower%5d)
- [Reyhan, Last of the Abzan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReyhan%2c%20Last%20of%20the%20Abzan%5d) + Kraum, Ludevic's Opus
- Reyhan, Last of the Abzan + [Ludevic, Necro-Alchemist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLudevic%2c%20Necro-Alchemist%5d)
- Ikra Shidiqi, the Usuper + Ludevic, Necro-Alchemist